# How to connect speaker cables via S-Video plug

Tags: cables, sound, speakers, plug

I would like to buy a speaker system consisting of an active subwoofer and two satellites. From the photos I can see, that the satellites are connected to the central sub using supplied cables with S-Video plug. I would like however to use my own cables already embedded in the plaster of my walls.

The question is: how should I terminate my cables with the plugs? I believe they still use only two pins of S-Video plug, but which ones? Is there any standard for this?

Comment: Which speaker system?  I can't imagine they are really using an S-Video connector.  It is more likely something else.  Please post a link to the speaker.

Comment: I can.  I've seen it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's mini-DIN 2-pin, there's mini-DIN 3-pin, there's mini-DIN 4-pin ("s-video"), there's mini-DIN a;; the way up to 8 or 9 pins as I recall.

There's no way for us to know at all which they are really using and how. Mini DIN is just a connector, S-Video is a signal standard that happens to run over mini-DIN 4.

Cheaper construction houses for audio systems will use any connector they can get their mitts on for whatever reason they are thinking of. Usually something along the lines of "single plug, marketing gimmick, awesome". The thing is, they will also put it on any which way they tend to enjoy at that time: Boom! new "standard".

Don't expect there to be any consistency in non-standard solutions.

Main-stream brands will normally use one of the standard two ways of hooking up speakers:

- Wire-end and heavy duty clamps. (~90% I'd estimate)
- Banana plugs. (~10% Again, estimated)